# Prometheus - Multiple average HTTP request rate over a given period

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I have an HTTP API for which I need to find:

1. Average number of requests per second during the last N days
2. Average number of requests per hour during the last N days
3. Average number of requests per day during the last N days

Is `rate(http_requests_total[Nd])` the right and best answer to 1? 
And if so, for 2 and 3, is it enough to multiple by 60x60 and 60x60x24,respectively?

Answer (score 0):

> is it enough to multiple by 60x60 and 60x60x24,respectively?

Yes, using `rate` and then multiplying is the way to do this.